# Greasemonkey Display Alert Once

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Is it possible to display an alert only once when a greasemonkey script is first loaded? I want it to tell the user that the script has upgraded to the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the last stored version and check against the actual one:

```
// ==UserScript==
...............
// @version       2.0.1
...............
// ==/UserScript==

if (GM_getValue("version", "") < "2.0.1") {
   GM_setValue("version", "2.0.1");
   alert("Updated");
}
```

All three version instances should be updated of course when you change the script.

Comment: Had some issues but it was because I had to grant `getValue` and `setValue`